# CodeBuild upload build artifact to S3 with ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, aws-codebuild

I have 2 AWS accounts. Lets say A and B.

Account A uses CodeBuild to build and upload artifacts to an S3 bucket owned by B. B account has set a ACL permission for the bucket in order to give Write permissions to A.

The artifact file is successfully uploaded to the S3 bucket. However, B account doesnt have any permission over the file, since the file is owned by A.

Account A can change the ownership by running

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket bucket-name --key key-name --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

But this has to be manually run after every build from A account. How can I grant permissions to account B through CodeBuild procedure? Or how can account B override this ownership permission error.

The CodeBuild starts automatically with web-hooks and my buildspec is this:

```
 version: 0.2
 env:
 phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk8
    commands:
      - echo Entered the install phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the build phase...
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the post_build phase...
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'myFile.txt'
```

Comment: Does the codebuild artifacts bucketOwnerAccess setting help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using aws cli commands from the build phase.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn install...
      - aws s3 cp my-file s3://bucketName --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

I am using the build phase, since post_build will be executed even if the build was not successful.

edit: updated answer with a sample.

Answer (score 2):

CodeBuild does not natively support writing artifact to a different account as it does not set proper ACL on the cross account object. This is the reason the following limitation is called out in the CodePipeline documentation:

> > Cross-account actions are not supported for the following action types:
> >
> > - Jenkins build actions
> > - CodeBuild build or test actions
> >
> > https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html

One workaround is setting the ACL on the artifact yourself in the CodeBuild:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3api list-objects --bucket testingbucket --prefix CFNtest/OutputArti >> $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/objects.json
      - |
        for i in $(jq -r '.Contents[]|.Key' $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/objects.json); do
          echo $i
          aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket testingbucket --key $i --acl bucket-owner-full-control
        done
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I did the something similar. However, in my situation, I had to upload a new artifact with each new build. So I had to find a way to upload the artifact with correct ACL. I think the above solution, only changes the ACL. And post_build happens before the artifact upload step.