# S3 objects deny access - These objects came from another account's AWS CodeBuild project

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-codebuild

(+)
I just found a similar question and answer with help from petrch (thanks!) and being try to apply... 
[CodeBuild upload build artifact to S3 with ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098329/codebuild-upload-build-artifact-to-s3-with-acl)

---

I'm updating accountB's S3 bucket by accountA's CodeBuild project. 
A problem is, all the object from accountA's CodeBuild deny to access.

My purpose is using this S3 bucket for static hosting.
I set all requirements for static hosting and it's working fine when I uploaded simple index.html manually.

But the individual object from accountA's CodeBuild project show below attached error. 
ex) index.html properties & permission

I checked the `Disable artifact encryption` option in the artifact setting in the CodeBuild project.
and also on the override params,
`encryptionDisabled: true`

This code build project is working fine when I save the output in the same account S3. 
(S3 static hosting site in AccountA is working well)
But getting access issue in accountB's S3.

Before try to touch KMS policy, I want to know if I missed some configurations in the CodeBuild.

Please advice me what I have to do or missed...

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(+)
I just found a similar question and answer with help from petrch (thanks!) and being try to apply... 
[CodeBuild upload build artifact to S3 with ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098329/codebuild-upload-build-artifact-to-s3-with-acl)

---

Upload the objects with `bucket-owner-full-control` canned ACL, otherwise the objects will be still "owned" by the source account.
See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html

It says:

> Amazon S3 access control lists (ACLs) enable you to manage access to buckets and objects. Each bucket and **object** has an ACL attached to it as a subresource. It defines which AWS accounts or groups are granted access and the type of access. When a request is received against a resource, Amazon S3 checks the corresponding ACL to verify that the requester has the necessary access permissions.
> When you create a bucket or an object, Amazon S3 creates a default ACL that grants the resource owner full control over the resource. This is shown in the following sample bucket ACL (the default object ACL has the same structure)

So the object has ACL of the source bucket, it's not very obvious, but you can provide an ACL during the PutObject action from the source account. So it can still be just one call.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, petrch.. It seems I clicked wrong edit button last night and updated your answer. I moved that wrong additional sentence to my text. I'm trying to apply your answer. Will update soon.